# using a variable to Set rst

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to open a record set using a SQL string. I get run time error 3061 "Too Few Parameters." any help would be appreciated.

```
Dim stAppName As String
Dim stURL As String
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim dbs As Database
Dim stringToSearch As Integer
Dim strSQL As String

Set dbs = CurrentDb


stringToSearch = InputBox("What is your route #?", "Enter route #: ")


strSQL = "SELECT ESRP.* FROM ESRP WHERE ESRP.Route=stringToSearch"

Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

Comment: Variables go outside the quotes, but this is a really bad idea. Have a look at parameters, eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631552/ms-access-query-reuse-supplying-query-parameters-using-vba/4631570#4631570, but you will find many examples.

Comment: Thanks, should have realized it. I have a do while not EOF that loops through and gathers variables th build a URL for google maps. My drivers now (that I have the last piece of the puzzle) enter a route number and get driving directions, stop by stop, for an entire route.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the code line of strSQL as follows, as suggested by Fionnuala you need to use variable outside the quotes.

Assuming Route field is Text data type, we need to put single quote for strings, if its number no single quote, for dates put # instead of single quote

```
strSQL = "SELECT ESRP.* FROM ESRP WHERE ESRP.Route='" & stringToSearch & "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little sample, maybe it can help you

```
Public Function fn_SQL_dbOpenRecordset(Optional vsql As String = "") As Recordset

    Dim dbs       As DAO.Database 

    Dim rs As Recordset
    On Error GoTo END_CODE

    'Set the database
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(vsql, dbOpenForwardOnly) 'you can use: dbOpenDynamic; dbOpenSnapshot; dbOpenTable

    Set fn_SQL_dbOpenRecordset = rs

    Exit Function

END_CODE:
    Set fn_SQL_dbOpenRecordset = Nothing
End Function


Public Sub Program_Test()

    On Error GoTo ERROR_SUB
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim sName As String


    sName = "Joe"
    sName = "'" & sName & "'" 'WARNING: BE CAREFUL WITH SQL INJECTION !!! Google it

    Set rs = fn_SQL_dbOpenRecordset("select * from  table1 d where PersonName = " & sName)

    Dim i As Long
    i = 0

    While Not rs.EOF
      Debug.Print rs(0).Value & " - " & rs(1).Value
      rs.MoveNext
    Wend

ERROR_SUB:

     On Error Resume Next
     If Not rs Is Nothing Then rs.Close
     Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```